# Accessing GUI object from a different method

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to access a variable that is a part of my GUIClass so I have created a new class where I instantiate my static GUI and give it a setter and from a different GUI class I call this setter to get all the variables I need.

Is this the correct approach or is there a better way?

```
public class Master {

    static NormalDistributionUI ndUI;

    public static NormalDistributionUI getNdUI() {
        return ndUI;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ndUI = new NormalDistributionUI();

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ndUI.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

One more thing since I have moved main to this class I am not sure what to do now with:

```
   try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
```

or rather where this should be executed, in GUI constructor?

**EDIT:** Picture showing what I am trying to achieve
[image]

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a M-V-C design, but hard to say. I worry that your use of static here is a "tail wagging the dog" solution. Please tell more, show more, explain more.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank you for response, I have added a picture with what I am trying to achieve maybe that will clear it up a little

Answer (score 2):

I would look into using the [M-V-C or Model-View-Controller design pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127624/what-is-mvc-really) or one of its many variants for this where

- Your model contains your data table
- It also contains information on selected integration type
- The control will listen to responses made in the Preferences dialog and notify the model of the selections made
- This will change the state of the model: its integration type would change, and likely its data would be re-calculated based on this integration type.
- The view listens to changes in the model (in one version of MVC) and then re-displays the new data when notified by the model of data changes.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I have read in the past a lot about MVC is there a simple implementation guide you could suggest?

Comment: @Higeath: best is the link that I've provided. You'll need to create your classes to fit your needs I'm afraid.

Comment: @Higeath: though if you simplify your code to a valid [mcve], I may be able to help more directly.

Answer (score 1):

Make your GUI class [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). Your code should look like the following at the end. (and of course use the @Hovercraft Full Of Eels suggestions)

```
 public class NormalDistributionUI { 

         private static NormalDistributionUI _instance = null; 

         /*It's important that the constructor is private*/ 
         private NormalDistributionUI(){ 
                 //constructor 
         } 

         // your class body 


         /* public static method to retrieve your instance */
         public static NormalDistributionUI getInstance(){ 
                 if(_instance == null) 
                         _instance = new NormalDistributionUI(); 
                 return _instance; 
         } 
 } 

 /* your Master class goes like this */
 public class Master { 

         //your class 

         public static void main(String[] args) { 

                 java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() { 
                         public void run() { 
                                 NormalDistributionUI.getInstance().setVisible(true); 
                         } 
                 }); 
         } 

 }
```